# Freebase: Is there a quota limit using a cursor?

Tags: python, paging, freebase, mql

I'm using the "new" freebase API in combination with the google-api-python-client (1.0) to select movies which match a specific pattern. I do this by using  a cursor and a limit statement.

The problem is, that after about 8000 selected movies I get a HTTP Error 503 "Backend Error".

I tried different limit values (500, 250, 100) and it always happens at the same number of selected entities. I implemented a simple exponential growing retry interval but even after 20 minutes the request resulted in that error while a fresh request (with an empty cursor) started selecting again.

I hope one of you can explain this to me or give me hint what I'm doing wrong. I couldn't find any information that there is another quota limit besides the 100k/day request limit (which I didn't reach).

Thank you very much.

Martin

Comment: when I just select the ID of the movies, the error occurs after selecting 15K instances. Maybe there is a traffic limit / time?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered on the Freebase mailing list and the problem turned out to be bad data in the graph that was causing the query engine to choke.  Specifically it was key values which had newlines appended to them.  Changing the query slightly so that the data was returned different allowed the problem to be worked around, but it didn't have anything to do with the query, quotas, or client libraries.

The problem is described in this [bug report](http://bugs.freebase.com/browse/FREEBASE-2827).